# Show symbols on image while mouse on picture

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Currently, I'm working on simple card recipe on VueJS and have a little problem. While mouse is on image, I would like to show diffrent properties of my recipe(like in this picture https://pasteboard.co/JrWe5JB.png). Firstly I darken a little bit my image and trying to display symbol on this(while mouse is on ofc), but it doesn't seem work. Here is my code:
CSS

```
.imageRecipeContainer
{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.imagePerfumeRate
{
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.card-image {
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.card-image:hover
{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(30%);
   filter: brightness(30%);
}
.card-image:hover .imagePerfumeRate
{
  display: block;
}
```

and code in Vue:

```
<div class="imageRecipeContainer">
        <img class="card-image" :src="card.image"/>
        <img class="imagePerfumeRate" :src="require('../assets/2PointPerfumeRate.svg')"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `src` can end with `.image` ? Don't you mean `.png` or `.jpg`? Because I haven't heard about `.image`

Comment: @php123 In Vue it would be a binded data property, so `card` is an object

Comment: @Pandor have you tried the sibling operator: `~`? `.card-image:hover ~ .imagePerfumeRate`

Comment: Yes, card is an object and atribute .image is path to example picture.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, OK, good to know

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I have antoher question to you. While I mouse on my symbols it seems   flashing all time. Have you got any idea to treat this symnbols like a layer(while mouse on it nothing happens) ??